# morphia MappingException: Error setting value from converter (IdentityConverter)

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Due to issues observed during bulk-write, I am trying to upgrade Morphia jar of my project.

From Morphia 0.99 to 1.1.1. After update I am having problem while reading Embedded class objects, which implemented Iterable.

Following is the error I am seeing while reading, persisted record:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from
>   converter (IdentityConverter)

I am using Mongo 2.7.3, I can not do an upgrade at the moment.

EDIT: Full stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (IdentityConverter) for Doc.expressionTraversalTree to { "levels" : [ { "computeUnits" : [ { "computeType" : "MATH_EVAL" , "mvalExpression" : "doc['__count__'].value  +  10" }] , "level" : 0}]}
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:74)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:772)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:230)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:191)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:220)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.dao.BasicDAO.findOne(BasicDAO.java:188)
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (IdentityConverter) for Doc.expressionTraversalTree to { "levels" : [ { "computeUnits" : [ { "computeType" : "MATH_EVAL" , "mvalExpression" : "doc['__count__'].value  +  10" }] , "level" : 0}]}
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:74)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:768)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:230)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readMapOrCollectionOrEntity(EmbeddedMapper.java:206)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:142)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:45)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (IdentityConverter) for Doc.expressionTraversalTree to { "levels" : [ { "computeUnits" : [ { "computeType" : "MATH_EVAL" , "mvalExpression" : "doc['__count__'].value  +  10" , "computeLevel" : 0 , "applyFilter" : false  }] , "level" : 0}]}
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.Converters.fromDBObject(Converters.java:128)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:56)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ComputeExpTraversalTree field Doc.expressionTraversalTree to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.setFieldValue(MappedField.java:410)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.Converters.fromDBObject(Converters.java:126)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: It would help seeing the actual stack trace.  There's often a "caused by" section that's helpful to see.

Comment: @evanchooly I have added the stack trace. Please verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Posting as an answer, as it might help someone.

Root cause was with the object field 'ComputeExpTraversalTree', Morphia was not able to convert this object to Mongo's BasicDBObject.

I have added a custom Converter which will encode and decode the field to & from BasicDBObject.

Snippet of Converter and how to configure this on Morphia client.

Converter class:

```
public class ComputeExpressionTreeConverter extends TypeConverter implements SimpleValueConverter {

    public ComputeExpressionTreeConverter() {
        super(ComputeExpTraversalTree.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object encode(Object value, MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        DBObject dbo = null;
        String expressionTree=new Gson().toJson(
                value, ComputeExpTraversalTree.class);
        dbo=BasicDBObject.parse(expressionTree);
        return dbo;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Object decode(Class targetClass, Object fromDBObject, MappedField field) throws MappingException {
        if (fromDBObject == null) {
            return null;
        }
        DBObject dbo = (DBObject) fromDBObject;
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(dbo.toString());
        ComputeExpTraversalTree expTraversalTree = new Gson().fromJson(
                jsonElement, ComputeExpTraversalTree.class);
        return expTraversalTree;
    }

}
```

Configuration:

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.getMapper().getConverters().addConverter(cls);
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Why I can't find ComputeExpTraversalTree?

Comment: Probably deprecated in current version. I am not using the library these days